# Azure Functions Billing Async Methods

Tags: azure, azure-functions, billing

When using Azure Functions based on a Consumption Based Plan that preform an `async` task, are you billed at the same rate if you `await` them vs. not `awaiting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that does not affect the billing. Billing timer is simply based on the amount of time between the start and the end of the function.

However, writing proper async code is always preferable from a scaling standpoint.

Comment: If async calls are sequential, why is it still preferable? In what way will it help scale a function?

Comment: Azure Functions tries to run multiple instances of a Function App in the same instance (in addition to scaling to multiple instances). By using async code, you'll be able to run more in one instance, since it doesn't lock any threads. This will in turn reduce cold starts which happen when additional instances need to start.